# É correto se usar o verbo "voltar-se" no sentido de "tornar-se", de "transformar-se em"?

Tags: gramática

Como no seguinte exemplo: "Basta um corte da besta, um raspão, e um homem torna-se hospedeiro da morte. Presa 'volta-se' predador".

Repetindo, "volta-se" no sentido de "torna-se", isto procede, há exemplos?

Comment: Acho que não: https://dicionario.priberam.org/voltar se tornar e se virar.

Comment: J.G., bem-vindo ao site. Esse exemplo é de onde? Ouviste ou leste algures? Podes indicar a fonte?

Comment: O verbo *voltar* pode significar transformação, mas se usa como *voltar X em Y*, tal como «O Garoto, em grande milagre, voltou água em vinho». Isto excluindo que *voltar a* pode significar transformar-se a um estado anterior, como em «Voltou ao normal». Podes vê-lo no [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v6-0/html/index.php#6) (acepção 9) e no [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/%20voltar) (acepção 19).